# Why aren't all Stack Exchange communities as active as Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

It's just sometimes a little depressing when one steps foot into one of the smaller communities. You know, like when there are only 48,429 questions and the most highly-voted one only has 587 votes. Why can't they all have more than 155,000 pages of users like Stack Overflow?

Comment: umm... Stack Exchange has no magic wand to draw new people into their sites.

Comment: @ShadowWizard This really is a serious question. Is it really that there are more programmers in the world than there are Android Enthusiasts (not picking on that community), and so the magic dice just happened to come up with snake eyes more times? Or is there something about some of the Stack Exchange communities that simply isn't attractive to people, or that isn't conducive to stuff?

Comment: It is all about establishing a solid users base. Stack Overflow started with such a users base of people following Jeff blog.

Comment: There is no obligation to explain downvotes

Comment: @ShadowWizard So this means the large bases of users are already elsewhere, right? And by implication does this mean I should go to those other places instead of to a SE community if I want a quick, quality answer?

Comment: @Tropiks Correct. But I would like to encourage the downvoters to explain themselves. Otherwise I'm left wondering what's wrong and am much more likely to post another (presumably) bad question in the future

Comment: Stack Overflow had a [9 month head start](http://stackexchange.com/sites#oldest) on the next site in the Stack Exchange network but that will only explain some of its dominance.  There will be too many reasons to list in an answer here as to why each of the other 157 Stack Exchange sites has not "caught up" which makes this question too broad.

Comment: @PolyGeo I'd be interested to hear your thoughts on maybe a couple of other reasons you've seen besides the head start

Comment: It's a question akin to why doesn't every country have the same population as China i.e. more suited for the water cooler or a chat room, I think.  Personally, I enjoy my time spent in several smaller communities much more than that I spend in Stack Overflow, so depressing is the last way that I would describe it.

Comment: @PolyGeo I appreciate your input

Comment: Because the SE Inc intentionally groups its resources to the SO.

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of reasons, mainly due to interest, expertise, scope, breadth of topics etc.

Also consider the amount of time that Stack Overflow has been in existence compared to other sites. Some of the smaller sites are considerably younger, thus have had less time to attract active members.

As mentioned in the comments, Stack Overflow had the 'head start' advantage of a solid userbase (discussed back in 2008 [here](https://blog.codinghorror.com/stack-overflow-none-of-us-is-as-dumb-as-all-of-us/) at the very beginning of the Stack Overflow's existence).

Comment: Time is minor, Stack Overflow started with a solid users base, migrated from Jeff personal blog. (I think)

Comment: @ShadowWizard added that in

Comment: Cheers, nice find of the blog post. :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, to be in a community - you need to know about that community as well.

I think it is quite observable that when you meet a programmer, he is more likely to know what Stack Exchange is than a Hindu you meet ([I just noticed, there is a community for that!](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/)), or a [gardener](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/), or a [photographer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/).

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is the only site where one an really ask about almost anything related to programming from anyone and have it noticed easily. (All languages have their own forum + stuff like [MSDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Developer_Network) and all - it's quite jumbled - going to Stack Overflow and asking is mostly easier!)

Arduino on the other hand has many active forums, and therefore [Stack Exchange's Arduino site](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/tour) is not the only one. Maybe it gets more hits than the [Arduino.cc forum](https://forum.arduino.cc/) - I don't know.

Electrical Engineering - OK for this one; you are definitely not going to get hits from "developing" countries (like [India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India)) - I am talking from my personal experience - these people barely know about the Internet (and don't judge me, most engineers from India barely know about online forums, except maybe [Quora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quora) - because their policies are not as strict, and they do allow you to write some pretty bad answers).

Coming to a competitor which has grown quite big in India (the second largest internet consumer, behind the Chinese, who usually stick to Chinese forums.) - Quora - as I mentioned - the users of this site - (I am one since at least 2012 - when it was not FILLED with Indians - it was quite good) - do not promote critical thinking and just keep boasting about their country or something similar --- let's call it some that will be unacceptable in most of Stack Exchange.
So many scientists have joined Quora (it promotes their answers in my view - you will definitely encounter a famous person on Quora once, but on Stack Exchange? Maybe). The "learners" will probably stick to Quora to ask silly stuff.

So that leaves only special communities like the one for [Vi*](https://vi.stackexchange.com/), [cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/), [Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) (quite big), [Ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/), etc. which have *almost* no other forum as big as their Stack Exchange sites to ask stuff.

Note: I did not do any strong research for this answer - everything is my wild guess - if you do know better stats than me then please correct my answer.

Comment: Yes, it has been described as "*[it's more like Yahoo Answers but written by smug douchebags with slightly better grammar](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-admitting-to-write-on-Quora-a-turn-off-on-a-first-or-second-date/answers/13097698)*".